# How do I call an rvalue member function from another rvalue member function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a class that is only supposed to exist temporarily. I'm using this to create an interface similar to the partial application of a function. Here's a silly example of what I'm trying to do.

```
struct Adder {
  explicit Adder(const int &leftOp)
    : leftOp(leftOp) {}

  int add(const int rightOp) const {
    return leftOp + rightOp;
  }

  //note that addTwice calls add
  int addTwice(const int rightOp) const {
    return add(rightOp) + add(rightOp);
  }

private:
  const int &leftOp;
};

struct Calculator {
  explicit Calculator(const int leftOp)
    : leftOp(leftOp) {}      

  Adder add() const {
    return Adder(leftOp);
  }

  void setLeftOp(const int newLeftOp) {
    leftOp = newLeftOp;
  }

private:
  int leftOp;
};
```

The calculator is used like this.

```
Calculator myCalculator(4);
const int myNum = myCalculator.add().add(5);
std::cout << myNum << '\n'; // 9
```

I want to restrict the interface of `Adder` so that it can only be called as above. I want the compiler to stop users from storing an `Adder` in a variable.

```
auto myCalcPtr = std::make_unique<Calculator>(4);
const Adder adder = myCalcPtr->add();
myCalcPtr.reset();
//oh dear. Adder has a dangling reference to a member in Calculator
const int myNum = adder.add(5);
```

My immediate thought was to mark `Adder::add` and `Adder::addTwice` as `&&` like so

```
int add(const int rightOp) && {
  return leftOp + rightOp;
}
int addTwice(const in rightOp) && {
  return add(rightOp) + add(rightOp);
}
```

but I got compiler errors in `Adder::addTwice`. The error was

```
No matching member function for call to `add`
Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Adder' but method is not marked const
```

So I added made both functions `const &&` like so

```
int add(const int rightOp) const && {
  return leftOp + rightOp;
}
int addTwice(const in rightOp) const && {
  return add(rightOp) + add(rightOp);
}
```

but still got the same error then I came to stackoverflow and asked

**How do force all instances of Adder to always be a tempory?**

My actual problem is much more complicated than the above example. I'm not a beginner asking about homework!

Comment: `void` return types but returning x + y? I think you need to revisit this example code.

Comment: Woops! Thanks for pointing that out Richard

Comment: Also your `addTwice`, wich I would expect to act like calling `add` twice with the same parameter, actually does this: `2 * (leftOp + rightOp)`. But since this is just an example I don't think this will bother you.

Comment: Seems like in this case, probably fine to make `Adder` a `private` 'member' of `Calculator`.

Comment: Nicky C. Sort of. I had a huge class that had too many responsibilities so I did what any good programmer would do and I drew a graph of the flow of data. Then I used the graph to slice the giant class into 9 classes. In order to pull the implementation of Adder out of Calculator, I need to do something like this

Comment: That's not the sort of solution I was looking for. There'd be duplicate data between Calculator and Adder.

Comment: StoryTeller I put it between the ) and the {

Comment: You're absolutely right StoryTeller. I'll get onto that right away

Comment: Anyway, took a while, but finally found the duplicate. `*this` is always an lvalue inside member functions. You need to rely on `std::move`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your help StoryTeller